# Deleting rows With 0 Values under a certain Variable in Data frame

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics

So I have a data frame.

In which some specific variables may have the value of 0. But I want to delete the row only if the value of zero shows up on 3 or 4 of these specific variables.

Thank you

Comment: trry `df1 %>% filter_at(yourvars, all_vars(. != 0))`

Comment: Please edit your question according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with `filter_at` by specifying the columns of interest

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   filter_at(vars(col1, col2), all_vars(. != 0))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(0, 1, 2, 3), col2 = c(1, 0, 2, 4), col3 = c(1, 1, 0, 0))
```

Comment: So I have these variables:
login_count : whitch is integer
text_length: might be 1 to thousands
assignment: 1 to hundreds meaning he had an assignment
mindmap_length: also 1 to thousands ( Letter counting)
activity: also integer 1 to hunders
So basicaly a user to have values >0 on these values the value login must be at least 1 meaning he loged in to the system and wrote something
Then also Assignment has to have a value meaning the assignment he had to do
But login and assignment might be 1 and the others might be 0 and I still need to delete the row. So how i do if else here?

Comment: @AlexRika  I showed a reproducible example based on your description.  Sorry, it is not clear to me without a reproducible example

Comment: Edited it please check

Comment: @AlexRika  Please edit your post with a small example and your expected output.